# Dropdownlist for select option on DataTable does not work well, How to fix this issue on my JqueryUI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datatable

I have this code below, i want to have select options for column 'WhoAttend' and 'Description', so i implemented some dropdownlist using render to do this and was unfortunate until today. Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks mates and have seen the documentation on DataTable.net but i could not get this right. Surely i am missing some little bit of logic somehow and need some guidance to this logic below.

```
<h2>EventManagement List</h2>
<table id="EventsManagementsTable" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">


    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>TrainingType</th>
            <th>TrainingDescription</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Facilitator</th>
            <th>WhoAttend</th>
            <th>RSVP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


</table>


@section scripts{

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#EventsManagementsTable").DataTable({

                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "WhoAttend",
                        "name": "WhoAttend",
                        "render": function (value) {
                            return $("<select/>")
                                .addClass("form-control")
                                .attr("name", "WhoAttend")
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Engineers"))
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Inspectors"))
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Technicians"))
                                .val(value)
                                .html();
                        }
                    }

                ],

                "serverSide": "true",
                "order": [0, "asc"],
                "processing": "true",
                "paginng": true,
                "ordering":true,
                "language": {
                    "processing": "processing...... please wait"
                },

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Dashboard/GetData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "JSON"


                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "TrainingType", "name": "TrainingType", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "TrainingDescription", "name": "TrainingDescription", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Price", "name": "Price", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Venue", "name": "Venue", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Facilitator", "name": "Facilitator", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "WhoAttend", "name": "WhoAttend", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "RSVP", "name": "RSVP", "autoWidth": true },

                ]

            });

        });

    </script>

// Remodified code
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#EventsManagementsTable").DataTable({

                /*"columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "WhoAttend",
                        "name": "WhoAttend",
                        "render": function (value) {
                            return $("<select/>")
                                .addClass("form-control")
                                .attr("name", "WhoAttend")
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Engineers"))
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Inspectors"))
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Technicians"))
                                .val(value)
                                .html();
                        }
                    }

                ],
                */
                  "columns": [
                    { "data": "TrainingType", "name": "trainingType", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "TrainingDescription", "name": "trainingDescription", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Price", "name": "price", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Venue", "name": "venue", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Facilitator", "name": "facilitator", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "WhoAttend", "name": "whoAttend", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "RSVP", "name": "rsvp", "autoWidth": true },



                ],

                "serverSide": "true",
                "order": [0, "asc"],
                "processing": "true",
                "paging": true,
                "ordering":true,
                "language": {
                    "processing": "processing...... please wait"
                },

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Dashboard/GetData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "JSON"


                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what "does not work well" means?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the problem I would give you a few things to try:

1. You are defining "columns" definition twice. Once above and once below. It is likely to take the value of the second one and overwrite the first one you define up top so put the top one in the rest at the bottom an decide if you are going to override it.
2. Simple thing is paging is misspelled maybe:

   "paginng": true,

Change to "paging"

3. Validate the specified values for data such as "TrainingType" are the same as in the data set returned in the JSON from the server? For example is it like this:

{ "trainingType": {value}, "trainingDescription": {value}, "price": {value}, "venue":{value}, "facilitator": {value}, "whoAttend": {value}, "rsvp": {value} }

I only ask because often JSON data is returned in camel case so it would be good to check if the data table code is case sensitive?

Edit: Ah, I see what is going on this is that one thing where it doesn't like to make selects. I don't remember what the rationale for it was but anyways here is some code that will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EventsManagementsTable").DataTable({
        "serverSide": "true",
        "order": [0, "asc"],
        "processing": "true",
        "paging": true,
        "ordering":true,
        "language": {
            "processing": "processing...... please wait"
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Dashboard/GetData",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "JSON"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "trainingType", "name": "TrainingType", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "trainingDescription", "name": "TrainingDescription", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "price", "name": "Price", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "venue", "name": "Venue", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "facilitator", "name": "Facilitator", "autoWidth": true },
            {
                "data": "whoAttend",
                "name": "WhoAttend",
                "render": function (value) {
                    var sel = $('<select />')
                         .addClass("form-control")
                         .attr("name", "WhoAttend")
                         .append($("<option/>", { text: "Engineers", value: "Engineers" }))
                         .append($("<option/>", { text: "Inspectors", value: "Inspectors" }))
                         .append($("<option/>", { text: "Technicians", value: "Technicians" }))[0];

                    $(sel.options).each(function() {
                        if(this.value === value) {
                            $(this).attr("selected",true);
                        }
                    });

                    return sel.outerHTML;
                },
                "autoWidth": true
            },
            { "data": "rsvp", "name": "RSVP", "autoWidth": true }
        ]
    });
});
```

P.S. Don't hold the [0] part of that one line against me. It works. ;-) Maybe you could tell me why it works this way. I remember something like this happening before and someone told me why the val() doesn't select and why the select creation messes up and a more proper way to do it but I don't remember what it all was now. Anyways the code above should surely work now for sure.

Comment: i have done those now, i am still unable to get any luck even now.

Comment: Could you repost your modified code below the original.

Comment: Mathew i have reposted you can check

Comment: Alright I noticed it wasn't selecting the default item in the list so I added that as well. Happy coding!